# How to bind IP address to MAC address in Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, ip-address, mac-address

I want to bind IP address to MAC address on my computer, how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

`arp -s 192.168.1.1 00-22-44-66-88-AA`

binds 192.168.1.1 to 00:22:44:66:88:AA by static arp cache method...

Comment: If you meant, however, that you want a machine always allocated an ip address based on its MAC address, you need to set it in the router / DHCP server providing the IPs.

Comment: I want to bind an ip address to my MAC address permanently. How to do it?

Comment: I'd assume you are at home, using a internet/wifi router, and want IP address to be allocated per MAC address. Whether you can do this depends on whether your router support this feature. An easier alternative would be to setup the IP address manually instead of waiting it being dealt by the DHCP server...

Answer (score 0):

If your firewall/router is also your DHCP server, and it allows you to reserve IP addresses based on MAC address, you will need to configure it to do so. The method varies by brand (Linksys/D-Link/Netgear/Cisco and a thousand others) so you'll need to consult the web or the manual.

As bubu said in comments, it may be easier to simply assign a fixed IP address to your computer by editing the properties of your LAN connection. If you do so, make sure that the DHCP server will not assign that IP address to another computer that requests an address on your network.

Answer (score -2):

install wirelessmon software . right click on the mac address--->connect to AP--->check connect using mac---> connect